# How to add developer to google cloud platform with restricted permission but he should start instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have hired a google cloud window server 2012 machine for one of my developer in remote location to develop.

Since he is different timezone so I want him to start/stop the instance but I don't want to give him owner or any other permissions which enables him to download the code.

To fully protect the code I want him to give Editor role on the project but then he is unable to start the instance.

Can somebody please suggest how to achieve it where I can safeguard my code as well and he can start/stop the instance in his timezone for development?

Comment: Where is the code you're trying to protect?

Comment: It's hosted on a remote git server but cloned locally on cloud window 2012 machine.

Comment: OK so the only things you want to allow the developer to do are stop and start the instance? He's not allowed to RDP into the instance or anything like that? Look at the technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875480/can-google-compute-instances-be-started-and-stopped-on-a-schedule

Comment: Thanks for coming back on it. Sorry I wasn't clear.


I want developer to start/stop the instance as per his working times, remote desktop RDP to the instance and develop the code over there using a local window limited user. But I don't want him to have the facility of changing anything on the project settings, download the source code or any data from the cloud storage.


I just want him to perform his work but If I make him owner then I see that he can download google cloud SDK and can even download everything on the cloud machine.

Comment: Anybody who has answer to it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't make this person a GCP project user. Don't give him any GCP credentials. Use some variant of the above technique to start/stop the machine as needed to allow the developer to RDP in at certain times. How you control access to source files resident on that machine is really a Windows question, not a Google Cloud question.